# keep track of objects created from different mains

Tags: java, intellij-idea

**General idea:** I have 3 main type of objects.(Publisher, Broker, Consumer). Publisher is a server, broker is both server and client and consumer is a client.

**What i want to do is** to have a data structure (Arraylist) where i will keep track of the objects created.
For example, if i have 3 publishers(witch means 3 different mains), i want to be able to retrive an ArrayList with all the publishers created inside,  from what ever publisher i want.

I tried to to this by using a static ArrayList inside the publisher class and add every publisher created with the constructor but when i access it it shows only 1 publisher inside.

**What i ask is** if it is possible to have a list in the Publisher class where i will add all objects of type Publisher created from different mains. if not, do i need a socket communication or something?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify your problem and include some of the code you've written/what errors you have. Right now, your question is very broad and not really answerable.

Comment: Yeah it is very difficult to answer this question without knowing more.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah so if you have a Server that is going to communicate to and from another Server, you're going to have to provide some type of protocol where they can communicate with each other. This can be done with a LOT of different protocols but a few common ones, especially in Java, are TCP/UDP/HTTP. Generally you would use HTTP and then some architecture like REST.